# receive sessionid after login via spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security, dart, dart-polymer, spring-session

I am writing a small app with a spring boot rest based backend and a polymer dart based frontend.

Currently I'm struggling to receive the session id from the login mechanism...

Initially I planned to use the `HeaderHttpSessionStrategy` and use this to authenticate against the spring-session/redis session store to enable horizontal scaling.

The problem is that spring security always performs a redirect after login and in dart the `HttpRequest` class (from html package) and after the redirect the header field from the initial response is of course no longer present/accessible.
I tried to disable followRedirect for the client, but it looks like this is only available for the IO package `HttpRequest`.

Then I tried to switch to `CookieHttpSessionStrategy` but it looks like the dart httprequest does not store received cookies in the browsers cookie backend :-/

This should be a simple problem, but I'm a little bit lost here. This can't be that hard...

When I use for example the intellij rest client everything works and I can extract the session id from either the cookie or the header field...

Any ideas? :-/

Comment: There was a discussion recently which might be related https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/?nomobile=true#!topic/cloud/OPFK_0MkB3c

Comment: I saw that, but it seems to use dart:io which is not available in the browser :-(

Comment: It looks like it's way easier to write my own login filter that just doesn't redirect :-/

Answer (score 2):

It looks like dart always follows these redirects in the browser and I have no chance to retrieve the cookie or the token in the header of the first request.

So as alternative solution I'm trying to do this next:

Activate basic auth in spring security:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/logout").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionFixation().changeSessionId()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
...
}
```

In one controller I have something like this as a protected resource:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String login() {
    return RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSessionId();
}
```

This way you can get your session id as regular result. So I can simply fetch the ID from the response body and use it after I provide the correct basic auth credentials once.

This should only be used in trusted enviromnents or via https to make it harder for bad guys to sniff the credentials or session.

So basically this is what I do to log in:

```
void login() {
  Map<String, String> headers = {};
  authorize(headers);
  HttpRequest.request(LOGIN_URL, method: "POST", requestHeaders: headers)
  .then((request) => processLogin(request))
  .catchError((e) => processLoginError(e));

}

void processLogin(HttpRequest request) {
  sessionController.sessionId=request.responseText;
  mainApp.showHome();
}

void processLoginError(var e) {
  print("total failure to login because of $e");
}
String authorization() {
  String auth = window.btoa("$username:$password");
  return "Basic $auth";
}

void authorize(Map<String, String> headers) {
  headers.putIfAbsent("Authorization", () => authorization());
}
```

To send requests with `HeaderHttpSessionStrategy` I can do this:

```
void updateUserData(){
  _logger.info("Updating user data");
  Map<String, String> headers = {"Accept": "application/json", 'x-auth-token':sessionId};
  HttpRequest.request(USER_URL, method: "GET", requestHeaders: headers)
    .then((request) => processUserData(request))
    .catchError(ErrorHandler.handleHttpErrorGeneric);
}
```

You could also get it to work with cookies, but I like the `HttpRequest.request()` so it was easier to go with header fields.

Answer (score 0):

This [tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/securing-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-security) teaches you how to stop Spring Security from redirecting after successful or failed authentication.

> Authentication should Return 200 Instead of 301
>   Failed Authentication should return 401 instead of 302

Actually, I think the code in the tutorial is over complicated. For `MySavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` class, you just need one line in the `onAuthenticationSuccess` function:

```
clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
```